# How to calculate the Integral $\int_0^t\delta'(t-t')d t'$ (where $\delta'$ is a derivative w.r.t $t$, and $t'\in(0,t)$)?

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

Without choosing a specific representation for this distribution (by using something like a limit law on a Gaussian function):

How to calculate the Integral $\int_0^t\delta'(t-t')d t'$ (where $\delta'$ is a derivative of the Dirac Delta distribution, $\delta(t-t')$, with respect to $t$, and $t'\in(0,t)$)?

Is it correct to say that $\int_0^t\delta'(t-t')d t'=\delta(t)$? 
The latter is just some intuition I had, but have no real justification for it... maybe totally wrong..

Thanks!

Comment: If you took $s:= t-t'$ then $ds=-dt'$ and so your integral becomes

$$\int_0^t\delta'(s) ds\tag1$$

Now the distributional derivative of the Dirac distribution is defined by $\delta'(\varphi)=-\varphi(0)$ for any test function $\varphi$, however $s$ is not a test function so it is not clear what could be (or if it have) the meaning of $(1)$.

Comment: @Masacroso. You confuse two notations for distributions. Formally, a distribution is a linear functional which suggest writing $\delta'(\varphi) = -\varphi'(0)$. But informally, distributions are treated like functions and the variable $s$ in an expression like $\delta'(s)$ runs over $\mathbb{R}^n$, not over a space of test functions. An expression like $\int \delta'(s) \, \varphi(s) \, ds$ then means the same as $\delta'(\varphi)$ in the formal theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
\int_0^t \delta'(t-t') \, dt'
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \chi_{[0,t]}(t') \, \delta'(t-t') \, dt'
= (\chi_{[0,t]} * \delta')(t),
$$
where $*$ means [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution).

Now,
$$
\chi_{[0,t]} * \delta'
= (\chi_{[0,t]} * \delta)'
= (\chi_{[0,t]})'
= \delta_0 - \delta_t,
$$
i.e.
$$
(\chi_{[0,t]} * \delta')(t)
= \delta_0(t) - \delta_t(t)
.
$$

Unfortunately, the last term, $\delta_t(t)$ can only be given an infinite value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not sure that I understand it. So you are saying that the integral I wrote is diverging, no matter what is t and what is the range of t'? Can you please elaborate a little? What is \chi in your notation, and what is the meaning of the subscript t in \delta_t(t)?

Comment: The function $\chi_{[a,b]}(x)$ equals $1$ on $[a,b]$ and $0$ elsewhere. An integral $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx$ equals $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \chi_{[a,b]}(x) \, f(x) \, dx$.

Comment: Subscript $a$ on $\delta$ means that it's a unit mass at $a$, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta_a(x) \, f(x) \, dx = f(a)$. We have $\delta_a(x) = \delta(x-a)$.

Comment: Yes, I say that your integral diverges no matter what is $t$, and the main reason for this is that $\delta'(t-t')$ has its support at the end of the interval of integration. We're practically taking the derivative of $\chi_{[0,t]}(t')$ at $t'=t$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. As you said, it's unfortunate, but that's life ;). Would I get the same result if I do choose some specific limit representation of the Dirac delta?

Comment: There are some ways to get a finite result. One way is to say that the integral goes from $0$ to $t-$ (or $t+$), meaning that it goes to just to the left (right) of $t$. Then $\delta_t(t)$ will become $\delta_t(t\mp) = 0$ and the integral will be defined for $t \neq 0$ (for $t=0$ the first term in the final expression will be infinite).